# Python Split first "middle" and last word

Tags: python, split

I would like to split a list in 3 parts. It works except when the middle part is in "two parts".

```
file = open("/topladder/pr_top_fr","r")
for line in file:
    fields = line.split( )
    
    pos1 = fields[0]
    pos2 = fields[1]
    pos3 = fields[2]

    print("Position: " + pos1 + " - " + pos2 + " - Tr:" + pos3)
```

the file look like:

```
308 Mars 6249
948 Ben Stark 6063
955 Toto 6061
```

And here is the result:

```
Position: 308 - Mars - Tr:6249
Position: 948 - Ben - Tr:Stark
Position: 955 - Toto - Tr:6061
```

Is it possible to "combine" everything that is in the middle in "pos2"?
Thanks !!

Comment: What would be your desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file = open("/topladder/pr_top_fr","r")
for line in file:
    fields = line.split( )
    
    pos1 = fields[0]
    pos2 = fields[1:-1]
    pos3 = fields[-1]

    print("Position: " + pos1 + " - " + ' '.join(pos2) + " - Tr:" + pos3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach using `re` module:

```
import re
pos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(' ', string)]
part1 = string[:pos[0]]
part2 = string[pos[0]+1:pos[-1]]
part3 = string[pos[-1]+1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but

```
with open("/topladder/pr_top_fr","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        pos, *name, tr  = line.split( ) # using extended unpacking
        print(f"Position: {pos} - {' ',join(name)} - Tr: {tr}") # assume names were separated with space, not e.g. tab
```